# jQuery - submit form, add to db table, return success.

Tags: jquery, database, forms

As the title suggests, I want a form to be submitted via post to an external php file, have the data added to the db, and then have a success message be outputted.

As it stands, when I click submit on the form the page refreshes but nothing is added to the database. I don't get any message.

Here's my code:

jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $("form#submit").submit(function() {
            // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
            var value = $("#dropdown").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add_to_shelf.php",
        data: "shelf="+ value +"&bookID="+ $_GET['id'],
        success: function(){
            $('form#submit').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});

        }
    });
return false;
});
    });
```

HTML:

```
<form id="add_to_shelf_form" method="POST">
                    <select name="shelves" id="shelves">
                            <option value="1">Read</option>
                            <option value="2">Currently reading</option>
                            <option value="3">Want to read</option>
                     </select>  
                     <input type="submit" id="shelf_button" value="Submit" />
                     <p class="success">Shelf was successfully updated!</p>
            </form>
```

add_to_shelf.php:

```
include "base.php"; 
    include "session.php";

// SHELF INFORMATION
    $bookID = $_POST['bookID'];
$shelfID = $_POST['value']; 
    $userID = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$add_to_shelf  = "INSERT INTO books_on_shelves (bookID,shelfID,userID) VALUES ('$bookID','$shelfID','$userID')";
mysql_query($add_to_shelf) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: First of all, you really need to escape the input data to avoid SQL-injections. Have a look at PHPs `mysql_real_escape_string()` Second, what happens? Do you get any JS- or PHP-errors?

Comment: No, nothing happens. I get nothing. I click 'submit' and the page refreshes, but nothing happens.

Comment: I'm not concerned with sql injection right now - just want to get the code working :)

Answer (score 1):

The page refresh might be because the event isn't firing.  The return false should take care of that.

First, I would change `$("form#submit").submit` to `$("#add_to_shelf_form").submit`  That should at least get the event firing.

Also, you're definitely going to want to escape that input.  Don't insert user-supplied data into your database raw.  In the php, change this:

```
$bookID = $_POST['bookID'];
```

to:

```
$bookID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bookID']);
```

Comment: Ok, I've changed that, and nothing new is happening. Could it be an issue with the dropdown? I can get regular input fields to work fine, but not this for some reason.

Comment: If your jquery is configured correctly, the page will not refresh when you click "submit".  So, until that happens, the event is not attaching to your form.  The next step is to look at the developer console of the browser you're using to see if there is a javascript error.  @brian, could you recreate this issue on jsfiddle?

Comment: at your level of learning, you should really be doing everything in as few steps as possible.  Do the absolute simplest step, and then add more once you know that's working.  If you look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hYrrV/5/) you can see the code just showing "alert" when the form is submitted.  Do that, then move on to making the ajax request.

Also, things like sanitizing user input for sql, and properly indenting the code are good habits you should start forming now

Comment: I'm trying to give you reproducible steps to resolve these issues in the future.  You appear to trying to learn two separate technologies at once by integrating them.  You had the problem that your form event wasn't firing.  Now it is.  Replace the code that is showing the alert with the ajax request, and see if you receive the request on your server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8143/discussion-between-menacingly-and-brian-byrne)

Comment: Yes, did that, and it doesn't work. How can I tell if the problem lies with my ajax request or with my external php file?

Answer (score 1):

Your selector to catch the submit is incorrect. The `id` of your form according to the HTML you've posted is `add_to_shelf_form`, not `submit` which you use in your selector `form#submit`.

Try this instead:

```
$("#add_to_shelf_form").submit(...
```

**Update**

The reason it didn't work on fiddle was because of your `PHP $_GET[".."]` in the data, which broke the JS. I also added the data as an object instead of a variable, I believe it is a lot more readable.

I've updated your fiddle so that it works: http://jsfiddle.net/hYrrV/4/

In your page you will need to change the data object to from my static bookId to your dynamic generated by PHP:

```
data: { shelf: value, bookID: <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?> }
```

So your final code will be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#submit").submit(function() {
    // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
    var value = $("#dropdown").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add_to_shelf.php",
        data: { shelf: value, bookID: <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?> },
        success: function(){
            $('form#submit').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});

        }
    });

    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: How can I get $_GET data then?

Comment: @BrianByrne See my yet again updated answer with the final, complete code.

Comment: Thank you. The event is triggering now but for some reason the db isn't being updated :/

Comment: @BrianByrne Are you sure that you are hitting the PHP-file with your request? Could you just write something to the error log, or something like that, in the PHP-file so you now that the request is getting through.

Comment: @BrianByrne If your page is on a sub-directory on the server like yourdomain.com/somehting/page.php and your add_to_shelf.php is at the root of the domain, you might need to change the url option of the ajax-request to `url: "/add_to_shelf.php"` with a leading slash.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you have attached method to the submit button with id "submit" and that is not the case in your form. Id f button is "shelf_button" so it should be

```
$("#shelf_button").click(function() { ....
```

or you can attach event only on form.

Answer (score 0):

change `$("form#submit").submit(function() {` to `$("form").submit(function() {`

Answer (score 0):

try

> var value = $("#dropdown option:selected").val();

instead of

> var value = $("#dropdown").val();

because you are using select box.
and another one thing
try to get data value by this

> data: dataString,

and before make sure get dataString value something like this

> var dataString = 'shelves='+ shelves;